# Complex transfer function complex conjugate issue

Tags: transfer-function

Going through *Wireless Communication Electronics* from Robert Sobot and came across the following.  It's repeated throughout the book so my initial thought that it could be an error doesn't seem likely.

Where does the square root come from?

Multiplying the complex conjugate as shown gives me the same answer just without the roots on the denominators.

Is there a specific bit of information that is implied to reach the form they have?

[image]

Comment: It's a mistake. The `sqrt()` only comes for the non-squared absolute valued transfer function, e.g. if it were only the real part of (1.85), that would have been |H(w)|. If it happens once, "it happens", but if you say it's consistent throughout the book, then I'd choose a different book.

Comment: Excellent, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the author (or, just as likely, the grad students who did the heavy lifting) made mistakes in writing/editing the textbook. It happens far too often.

Not a lot of good proof-readers that can read these materials with understanding. And those that are good, these days anyway, aren't proof-reading but doing something that pays better.

(There was a time when "the rest of us" had better access to the better minds available. But that time is long gone (in the US) since very early in the Reagan Era (1981 and 1982 and 1983, in particular) when several significant changes to public science funding and patent law, for reasons requiring many hundreds of pages to explain, totally changed things here, and forever since.)

Their denominator, shown on the right side as \$\sqrt{1+\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}\$, is what arrives as the complex **magnitude** (length of the hypotenuse) of the denominator on the left. That does show up when you take the magnitude:

$$\begin{align*}
\bigg|\:\frac1{1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}\:\bigg| &= \frac{1}{\left|1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right|}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}
\end{align*}$$

But not when you are trying to put a complex transfer function into the standard mathematical complex form of \$a+b\,i\$.

So,

$$\frac1{1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}\cdot \frac{1-j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}{1-j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}=\frac{1-j\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}-j\frac{\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}$$

Which obviously isn't what they produced.

---

Their answer is easily tested. Just take the magnitude of their right hand side answer and see what you get:

$$\begin{align*}
\bigg|\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}-j\frac{\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}\:\bigg| &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}\right)^2}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac1{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}+\frac{\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{1}
\\\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

Their claim is that the magnitude is always 1 and independent of the angular frequency \$\omega\$.

I don't think so.

---

As concernedcitizen says, if this is just an isolated case and not representative of the textbook more generally, then it's just an **errata**. That happens (though this one isn't exactly a typo, either) from time to time. Nothing is perfect. But if this isn't rare in the textbook, it's time to replace the textbook, the teacher (who should have known better), and the administrative staff for the department (who **really** should have known better.) In general, this means leaving the institution and finding a better one, as I see it.

Comment: Back in 1967, I helped Jack Millman edit "Electronic Devices and Circuits" and worked all the problems for the TA's handbook. We were pleasantly surprised when the typesetters at McGraw Hill did their own derivations and calculations and corrected a few of our answers in the proofs.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg I gathered my microelectronics from Millman's textbook, circa 1980! It was one of the clearer expositions! I'm very glad to meet someone who knew him! And thanks for your contributions!

Comment: @jonk " I gathered my microelectronics from Millman's textbook".What do you mean ?

Comment: @JunSeo-He I mean that I started to learn about semiconductors using Millman's textbook, four decades ago. That's all.

Comment: Cheers for the helpful answer jonk, the book's the second edition but there are a million spelling / grammar errors but hopefully not many more technical errors like this. This isn't for a course in an institution, just personal study so not the end of the world but certainly not confidence inspiring

Comment: @Jonty I'm pretty much "personal study," myself. So identifying the better books is important to me. Sounds like your book was rushed out, which makes me interested in what motivated the authors or their publishers in the first place. Thanks for the kind words! It matters to me and I appreciate it.

Comment: What does patent law changes have to do with it? The only significant change in the mid ‘80s was having all patent appeals go to CAFC.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It started somewhat before the Bayh-Dole Act, though that was the first of several watershed events in my mind. You will have to work out the rest from there. No room in comments for a long discussion.